# <No main classes found> in java program

Tags: java

Hello I am writing a java program that converts Celsius to Fahrenheit.  A custom method will calculate the conversion and pass it to the main method which called it.. In the main method a loop will be invoked as long as 0-100 and increment by 10.. I have tried some of the other suggestions I have seen with this error but with no luck.. Here is my code and thanks in advance

```
package sknight_project10_orig;

public class SKnight_Project10_ORIG
{
    public static double main(String[] args)
    {
        double Celsius = 0.0;
        double Fahrenheit = 0.0;

        //For loop to increment by 10 from 0-100
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            convertTemp(Celsius);
            System.out.println(Celsius + " = " + Fahrenheit);
            i = i + 10;
        }
        return Celsius;
    } 

     public static Double convertTemp(Double Celsius)
    {
        double Fahrenheit = Celsius * 1.8 + 32;
        return Fahrenheit;
    } 
}
```

Comment: How you are running it ?

Comment: doesn't return double; main must return void.

Answer (score 0):

Main must return void:

```
package sknight_project10_orig;

public class TemperatureConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String arg : args) {
           double c = Double.parseDouble(arg); 
           System.out("c: " + c + " f: " + convertTemp(c));
        }
    } 

     public static double convertTemp(double c) {
        return 1.8*c+ 32;
    } 
}
```

Please learn and follow Java coding standards.  Your variable names are wrong.

Comment: you cannot return anything in a function with void

Comment: You don't need the return statement + fixed code a little bit :p

Comment: main doesn't return anything

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When I use void instead of double it tells me my return Celsius variable is an incompatible data type.

Comment: @ScottKnight check the entire implementation there are a few other changes !

Comment: So I can get rid of the return statement and it will still pass the Celsius variable?

Comment: main shouldn't return anything.   The compiler is telling you so.  No method with void return should have a return,

Comment: The above code worked great.. I noticed the changes and thank you

Answer (score 0):

A "main" needs void in its signature. How do you want to use the calculated value?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ ...
}
```

this is how the method should look like for a function called main that you are trying to run.

And now since it is "void", you should not return `Celsius`

You can print it out to make sure it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Main functions must return void, you can't return a double.
Here are a few things that were wrong:
- You never set Celcius before performing your convertTemp.
- Since Celcius is double, you'll have to cast it because i is int.
- You need to assign the result of convertTemp to Farhenheit.
- I won't fix it, but you need to use camelCase for your variable names, not PascalCase.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double Celsius = 0.0;
    double Fahrenheit = 0.0;

    //For loop to increment by 10 from 0-100
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i+=10)
    {
        Celcius = (double) i;
        Fahrenheit = convertTemp(Celsius);
        System.out.println(Celsius + " = " + Fahrenheit);
    }
}
```